# Not showing picklist value in LWC. I'm getting the data into console but not able to show it in html template. below is the code and screenshots

Tags: lightning-web-components

HTML FILE

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="FILTER" icon-name="standard:calibration">
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal_medium">
            <lightning-input label="SEARCH KEY" type="search" value={filter.searchKey}
            onchange={handleSearchKeyChange}></lightning-input>

            <section class="slider_section">
                <lightning-slider label="Max Price" step="100" min="0" max="9999999"
                value={filter.maxPrice} onchange={handleMaxPriceChange}></lightning-slider>
            </section>

            <section>
                <h2>CATEGORIES</h2>
                <template if:true={category.data}>
                    <template for:each={category.data.values} for:item="item">
                        <lightning-input key={item.value} name="CATEGORIES" label={item.label} type="checkbox"
                        checked onchange={handleCheckbox}></lightning-input>
                    </template>
                </template>
                <template if:true={category.error}>
                    <h1>error occured while loading</h1>
                </template>
            </section>

            <section>
                <h2>CAR COMPANIES</h2>
                <template if:true={CarMaker.data}>
                    <template for:each={CarMaker.data.values} for:item="item">
                        <lightning-input key={item.value} name="CAR COMPANY" label={item.label} type="checkbox"
                        checked onchange={handleCheckbox}></lightning-input>
                    </template>
                </template>
                <template if:true={CarMaker.error}>
                    <h1>error occured while loading</h1>
                </template>
            </section>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS FILE

```javascript
import { LightningElement,track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import CAR_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Car__c';
import CATEGORY_PICKLIST from '@salesforce/schema/Car__c.Category__c';
import MAKER_PICKLIST from '@salesforce/schema/Car__c.Maker__c';

export default class CarFilter extends LightningElement {
    filter={
       searchKey:"",
       maxPrice:9999999
    }

// FETCHING CATEGORY PICKLIST
@wire(getObjectInfo,{objectApiName:CAR_OBJECT})
carObjectInfo({data,error}){
    if(data){
        console.log(data)
    }
    else{
        console.log(error)
    }
}

@wire(getPicklistValues,{recordTypeId:"012000000000000AAA",
fieldApiName:CATEGORY_PICKLIST})category({data,error}){
    if(data){
        console.log(data)}
    if(error){
        console.log(error)}
}

// FETCHING MAKER PICKLIST
@wire(getPicklistValues,{recordTypeId:"012000000000000AAA",
fieldApiName:MAKER_PICKLIST})CarMaker({data,error}){
    if(data){console.log(data)}
    if(error){console.log(error)}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably because, initially the `CarMaker` and `category` are undefined, so accessing the data property will result in null pointer exception, therefore nothing will be shown.

Comment: Also, why not to use `checkbox-group`? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-checkbox-group/example

Comment: I didn't get your point can u please elaborate it

Comment: You are using checkboxes to display options of some field, for this use case is the checkbox-group.